# How to use Beautiful Soup to extract function string in <script>?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
html_code = """<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Title </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function answerQuiz() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("A")[0];
    x.innerHTML="Answer";
    x.style.color="black";
    }


function answerQuiz3() {
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName("B")[0];
      x.innerText="Contents";
    x.style.color="black";
    }

function answerQuiz2() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("C")[0];
    x.innerText="Quiz";
    x.style.color="black";
}

function answerQuiz4() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("D")[0];
    x.innerText="";
    x.style.color="red";
  }
</script>

</head>
</html>
"""
```

In this html code, I want to extract 'Answer', 'Contents', 'Quiz' from each function and innerText.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')

    answer_quiz_function = soup.find('script', string=lambda text: 'function answerQuiz' in text)

    match = re.search(r'\s*=\s*["\'](.+?)["\']', answer_quiz_function.string)
    if match:
        inner_text = match.group(1)

    print(inner_text)
```

But I can't extract string except from answerQuiz()
I mean, string from answerQuiz2(), answerQuiz3(), answerQuiz4() are not extracted.
Please help me.

Comment: you cannot use `bs4` to parse JS, only pure HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to get the innerText of all the functions:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find('script', type='text/javascript').string
re.findall("x.innerText=\"(.*)\";", text)
['Contents', 'Quiz', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall`. Notice that to match a JS-empty string you need to use `*` and not `+` in the regex.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')
script_tag = soup.find('script', string=lambda text: 'function answerQuiz' in text)

matches = re.findall(r'\s*=\s*["\'](.*?)["\']', script_tag.string)
for m in matches:
    print(m)
```

Output

```
Answer
black
Contents
black
Quiz
black

red
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `findall` for this which returns you a list.

That will give you

```
['Answer', 'black', 'Contents', 'black', 'Quiz', 'black', 'red']
```

If you want to fetch the Text and HTML use:

`re.findall(r'inner(?:Text|HTML)\s*=\s*["\'](.+?)["\']', answer_quiz_function.string)`

```
['Answer', 'Contents', 'Quiz']
```